# Error in Compilation of Maven Project: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have problems with Maven spring-boot:run.
When i press run, the process finishes with exit code 1.

Here, the execution details:

````
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.185 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-19T18:27:48-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.4:run (default-cli) on project prueba: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1```
---------------

Here is the pom.xml plugin file:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
````

Comment: Try a different java version, run with -e switch to get the actual exception.

Comment: Please provide the `pom.xml` file with the spring plugin on it